# htaccess specific string not working

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have this line in my .htaccess

```
RewriteRule ^values/?$ values.php [NC,L]
```

It is working perfectly in localhost, but when I uploaded it to the server, it is not working, goes to 404.

When I remove the 's', it works. Like this:

```
RewriteRule ^value/?$ values.php [NC,L]
```

How come? Thanks!

**EDIT**
added `Options -MultiViews` and it works

Answer (score 0):

Add Below line above rewrite rule and check if it works for you

```
 RewriteEngine On
```

So your code may look like

```
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteRule ^values/?$ values.php [S=3,NC,QSA,L]
```

Comment: I have `RewriteEngine On` . I have multiple rewrites, this is the only line that doesn't work

Comment: When I checked without `RewriteEngine On` I got an error for `value` (S removed) but after adding `RewriteEngine On` it displayed content of values.php with anyword in place of `values` i.e. with `values`, `value` and `val`

Comment: This might not be there but Are there any other rules for value or values.php?

Comment: Cool! . You can answer the question and accept it so that other can use it if needed.